# How to get the map annotations property in another class?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

I'm using the mapKit. I have created custom annotations with title, subtitle and an ID.
This is method that creates the annotation:

```
- (instancetype) initWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)paramCoordinates title: (NSString *)paramTitle subTitle:(NSString *)paramSubTitle ID:(NSString*)ID
{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil)
     {
    _coordinate = paramCoordinates; _title = paramTitle;
    _subtitle = paramSubTitle;
    _ID = ID;
     }
return self;
}
```

Now i use this to create annotations in another class:

```
-(void)createCityAnnotation
{
CLLocationCoordinate2D location1 =
CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(35.6961, 51.4231);
mapAnnotation *annotation1 =
[[mapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates:location1
                                     title:@"City 1"
                                  subTitle:@"XXX"
                                        ID:@"1"];
[self.myMapView addAnnotation:annotation1];

CLLocationCoordinate2D location2 =
CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.6333, 51.6500);
mapAnnotation *annotation2 =
[[mapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates:location2
                                     title:@"City2"
                                  subTitle:@"YYY"
                                        ID:@"2"];
[self.myMapView addAnnotation:annotation2];

CLLocationCoordinate2D location3 =
CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(38.0667, 46.3000);
mapAnnotation *annotation3 =
[[mapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates:location3
                                     title:@"City3"
                                  subTitle:@"WWW"
                                        ID:@"3"];
[self.myMapView addAnnotation:annotation3];
}
```

Now upon clicking on the annotations i want to be able to get the annotations ID in the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method. I dont know exactly how to do so.It would be something like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    ////Use the Annotations ID here.
    [table reloadData];
}
```

Comment: check view.annoatation is getting back or not.

Comment: i NSLog view.annotation and this is what i get: <mapAnnotation: 0x170648ca0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
     - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
        {
           mapAnnotation *annotaion= view.annotation;//this annotationWill be ur annotation.then u can get ID by annotation.ID.
NSLog(@"%@",annotation.ID);
        }
```

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here, ID is a NSString!

Comment: ur requirement is getting the ID back from this method, r8?

Comment: If it is sufficient for u, pls make tick mark on answer